# Javascript/Typescript if variable exists return if not return something else

Tags: javascript, typescript, if-statement

There is the syntax
`variable ? variable : something else`, but can I somehow leave out the second variable?

It would be cool to have a syntax like `variable ?: something else`.
Does something like this exists?

Thanks

Comment: `variable || something else` ([logical or](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR))? `variable ?? something else` ([nullish coalescing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator))?

Comment: [Nullish coalescing operator (??)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like `variable ?? something else` or `variable || something else` depending on what behaviour you want exactly

The nullish coalescing operator (??) is a logical operator that returns its right-hand side operand when its left-hand side operand is null or undefined, and otherwise returns its left-hand side operand.

This can be contrasted with the logical OR (||) operator, which returns the right-hand side operand if the left operand is any falsy value, not only null or undefined. In other words, if you use || to provide some default value to another variable foo, you may encounter unexpected behaviors if you consider some falsy values as usable (e.g., '' or 0). See below for more examples.

?? [Nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator)
|| [Logical OR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR)

Comment: Some explanation of what the difference between those two expressions is would go a long way to making this a useful answer.